# Disable widgets on specific posts

Tags: widgets, filters, sidebar, adsense

I run a horror related blog.  Google is upset with me for displaying adsense in a sidebar widget for one specific post number (4603) that contains an article about an 18+ topic.  How can I disable the widgets for a specific id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend the plugin Widget Logic to handle all your needs. You can just add logical tags to the individual widgets on the sidebar.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/

Answer (score 2):

You can filter `sidebars_widgets` and remove the widget you don’t need.

Example with a search widget; uncomment the debug code to find the correct identifier.

```
if ( ! is_admin() )
    add_filter( 'sidebars_widgets', 'remove_specific_widget' );

function remove_specific_widget( $widgets )
{
    if ( ! is_single( 402 ) ) // Post ID, title, slug, or array of such
        return $widgets;

    if ( ( $key = array_search( 'search-3', $widgets['primary-widget-area'] ) ) !== FALSE ) {
        unset( $widgets['primary-widget-area'][ $key ] );
    }

    // use this to inspect the current widget parameters
    //print '<pre>$widgets = ' . htmlspecialchars( var_export( $widgets, TRUE ), ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8', FALSE ) . '</pre>';

    return $widgets;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [Widget Manager Light](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sidebar-manager-light/) or [Display Widgets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-widgets/)  plugin for this. It's easier than using conditional tags or any code. You can see details on [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-show-or-hide-widgets-on-specific-wordpress-pages/).

**Widget Manager Light** let's you chose which widget to show on which post easily.

Thanks